# CheckBox marcada/desmarcada não obedece às instruções

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

A `Activity` é iniciada com o *layout* `activity_home` e a `CheckBox` desmarcada. Quando toco na `CheckBox`, o *layout* passa a ser o `activity_home_avancado`, **porém a `Checkbox` continua desmarcada.** No segundo toque, ela é marcada e o *layout* permanece como o avançado.
No terceiro toque, a `CheckBox` é desmarcada, porém o *layout* ativo **permanece** sendo o `activity_home_avancado`. Por quê esses dois erros?

Segue o código:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    final CheckBox checkBoxAvancado = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.modoavancado_cb);

    checkBoxAvancado.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBoxAvancado.isChecked()) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_avancado);
            }
            else {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            }
        }
    });


    } //fecha onCreate
}
```

E a mesma `CheckBox` presente nos dois arquivos *XML*:

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/modoavancado_cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#7F7F7F"
            android:text="@string/modoavancado" />
```

(nada aparece no LogCat)

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de, em cada um dos *Layouts*, as *CheckBox's* terem o mesmo ***id*** elas não são o mesmo objecto.

Quando é utilizado o método `(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.modoavancado_cb)`, este irá procurar o ***modoavancado_cb*** no *Layout* que foi associado à *Activity*, através de `setContentView()`

Quando é declarado o *listener*, para o *CheckedChanged*, este é associado à *CheckBox* do *Layout* `R.layout.activity_home` porque é esse o *Layout* que nesse momento está associado à *Activity*

O que está a acontecer é que o código do `onCheckedChanged()` só é executado uma vez.
Quando é atribuído o outro *Layout* à *Activity* em

```
if (checkBoxAvancado.isChecked()) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_avancado);
}
```

o *CheckBox* que aparece agora na tela é o definido no XML do *Layout* ***activity_home_avancado*** e não o do ***activity_home***.

Como este *CheckBox* não tem nenhum `OnCheckedChangeListener` associado, nada acontece quando é marcado.

O `setContentView` só deve ser utilizado uma vez.
Para mudar o conteúdo da tela crie outra *Activity*, utilize *Fragments* ou *hide/show* *Views* do *Layout*